# Saving LDAP User Entity in Database without Password

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, ldap

Theory: Is there a way to store an Ldap User in your own database, necassarly for relations, without the password and somehow still make refreshUser work?

*I have changed my system to work without having to store the pwd by checking on every login if the password matches the ldap server user password.
Symfony calls on every request the `refreshUser` method of your Provider, I have a custom LDAP Provider, to refresh the user using doctrine from the database. Symfony insures so that the object is always upToDate after an edit.*

The problem is that this method call the User Entity `getPassword()` method, which is not implement due to none pwd in db.

I have seen an approach to fix it, which is saving the Entity in an session and everytime when `refreshUser()` is called, returning the session entity. But then there is no way to get it always updated after edit. And I don't want to ruin the symfony infrastructure.

So is there an way to `refreshUser()` with maybe calling the LDAP Server again and asking if informations still match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-SOLVED-

Anyone having an application which relies on a ldap server authentification and a custom user entity inside your app database because of reasons, but you do not want to add the password for security reasons. Here is one answer:

**0. Remove pwd attribute equalivant inside db**

Inside your custom User Entity remove the *@Orm* Annotations to not persist the pwd into your database. Keep the attribute and Getter/Setter tho.

For example:

```php
//...
private string $password;
//...
```

**1. Add an custom LdapProvider**

Create a new class which extends `Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapUserProvider`. You may need to handle the DependencyInjections manuelly by adding your custom Provider inside your *services.yaml*:

```yaml
fullyQualified\NameSpace\CustomLdapProvider:
    arguments:
      - '@Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface' # I need the EM in __construct
      - '@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap'
      - # baseDn
      - # searchDN
      - # searchPassword
      - # roles
      - # uidKey
      - # filter optionaly, add null
      - # passwordAttribute
```

Override the methods 'supportsClass' and 'refreshUser' with the following code:

```php
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        return $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->find($user);
    }

    public function supportsClass(string $class): bool
    {
        return User::class === $class || is_subclass_of($class, User::class) || LdapUser::class === $class || is_subclass_of($class, LdapUser::class);
    }
```

Your `refreshUser()` method needs to return an User Entity. In my case I just return the user from the database.

*It is important, that your `supportsClass()` allows LdapUser and your own User Entity since on first login you will get an user from the ldap server which is `Symfony\Component\Ldap\Security\LdapUser`.*

**2. Add an EventSubscriber on InteractiveLogin**

Now you need to create an own User, if there is not already own, then continue with logging him in with the own user entity.

Create a new class which extends `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface` and use the event 'onInteractiveLogIn'.

```php
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => [
                ['onInteractiveLogIn', 0],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Inside 'onInteractiveLogIn()' you need to implement your way on creating a new custom User entity, if no found and persist it. Also creating a new `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;` for login.

My example:

```php
 public function onInteractiveLogIn(InteractiveLoginEvent $interactiveLoginEvent)
    {
        $ldapUser = $interactiveLoginEvent->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if (!($ldapUser instanceof LdapUser)) {
            return;
        }
        $localUser = // find local User with LdapUser credentials (Query);

        if (!$localUser) {
            // no custom user found, create own
            $localUser = new User();
            //...
        }
        // since we do not have pwd, fill it with anything to generate random token
        $rmdBytes = random_bytes(32);
        $localUser->setPassword($rmdBytes);

        $this->entityManager->persist($localUser);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        // login user with new created/already found custom user entity
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($localUser, $rmdBytes, 'main', $localUser->getRoles());
        $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    }
```

*Important: `onInteractiveLogIn` already validates that the entered pwd is equal to the real ldap pwd.*

**3. Implement own way to refresh User**

Since Symfony calls on every new request the refreshUser() method to provide an always fresh data object, we need to override the default behaviour.

Your `User` Entity needs to implement `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface`.

There you can change how on call of `refreshUser()`, the new refreshed User and the original User are compared. Default is password, but since we do not have a password, we do not want this behaviour.

In this example im comparing the UserIdentifieres, since they are unique:

```php
    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->getUserIdentifier() === $user->getUserIdentifier();
    }
```

4. Finished, Test it.

You should now be avaible to login without saving the pwd inside your own database.
The new system will call on every login the Ldap Server and asks for an user with given credentials. If then logged in it will not call the server anymore, instead will refresh the User automatically if matches the `isEqualTo()`.